# Serving static files from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have an Express server that contains a public folder containing 5 images. I want to load those images inside of my ReactJS app. How would I do that?

I'm already using:

```
app.use("/static", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

and I can access them when I manually type in the URL, but I'm unable to figure out how to serve them all in my React app.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to put them in your React app? As image tags?  What happens when you try this?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'm trying to put the in a gallery. So, display them all.

Comment: Is the express server also serving the React app, or is it separate?

Comment: `I'm unable to figure out how to serve them all in my React app.` - If you are able to see them by passing the URL in the browser, you just add the `src` same as the URL? What do you want to achieve any thing specific ?

Comment: They both run on the same port. So Express is serving React.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara YES, I'm able to view them one by one (browser), but I need to be able to get them all at once and display the on the client-side.

Comment: It should be as simple as `<img src="/static/path/to/some/image.png">`

Comment: @DzenisH. You need to then wait for all the images to be loaded and then show them. You can use promises to do it - request all the images and once you get all the promises resolved show them on the view.